# Can you ask questions about ENB Series mods, or if they'll work on games?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

As the title says, can you ask questions about ENB Series mods, or if they'll work on games?

Comment: How about providing a bit more context about what you're going after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're on topic and we have a few questions about these mods, both tangentially and directly; "Do ENB mods work with Game X" isn't a great question however, given that this is reasonably well documented right in the official website. (And in general, questions that can be boiled down to a simple yes/no *tend* to be poor questions.)

Comment: kay 'den, now i know.